# Should independent variables measured only once per set of replcations be duplicated in the data?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, sample, duplicate-records

I have a dataset from an experiment on soil erosion, where

1. soil samples `a`, `b` and `c` where collected, and
2. measurement of an independent soil property `x` was taken for each soil sample,

such as in the following small example:

```
  type   x
1    a 1.7
2    b 1.9
3    c 1.9
```

Next, four sub-samples from the each soil sample were subject to an experiment on soil erosion, where soil erosion metric `y` was measured. Technically, the "bucket" with each soil sample was divided to four sub-samples `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, then `y` was measured in each sub-sample:

```
   type repl   y
1     a    1 1.3
2     a    2 1.6
3     a    3 1.4
4     a    4 1.2
5     b    1 2.3
6     b    2 2.2
7     b    3 2.1
8     b    4 2.0
9     c    1 1.7
10    c    2 2.1
11    c    3 1.5
12    c    4 1.2
```

---

My **question** is: when analyzing the effects of `x` on `y`, such as using `lm` in R, which approach is more correct, (A) or (B)?

(A) Analyzing all 12 observations, while *duplicating* the measurement of `x` for each set of four sub-samples:

```
   type repl   x   y
1     a    1 1.7 1.3
2     a    2 1.7 1.6
3     a    3 1.7 1.4
4     a    4 1.7 1.2
5     b    1 1.9 2.3
6     b    2 1.9 2.2
7     b    3 1.9 2.1
8     b    4 1.9 2.0
9     c    1 1.9 1.7
10    c    2 1.9 2.1
11    c    3 1.9 1.5
12    c    4 1.9 1.2
```

(B) Analyzing the three observations, where outcome `y` is *averaged*:

```
  type   x     y
1    a 1.7 1.375
2    b 1.9 2.150
3    c 1.9 1.625
```

P.S. If the answer is (A), is it necessary to treat `type` as a random effect?

Thank you very much for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had more data points and more `type` categories, then a multilevel/mixed effects model estimated on data A would be the way to go. You could do this with your 12 data points, but this is an exceedingly small amount of data to estimate a multilevel or mixed effects model with. You can do so, but you will want to use a [small sample size correction](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-016-0809-y), specifically the Kenward-Roger degrees of freedom:

```
require(lmertest)
library(lme4)
m1.lmer <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|type), data=dat.A)
summary(m1.lmer, ddf="Kenward-Roger")
```

Even if you had more data points in each `type`, you only have 3 types. That is a very small number of groups for a multilevel/mixed effects modeling approach. Thus, unless you were prepared to use a Bayesian approach (completely reasonable if you know what you are doing), some people might say that a better frequentist option to use with the long data, what I called `dat.A`, is to estimate an OLS (`lm`) with a fixed effect of `type`:

```
m.lm1 <- lm(y ~ x + type, data=dat.A)
```

In this model, type is a 3 category dummy variable. The coefficient on `type` is an adjusted mean `y` value for the plot relative to the hold-out category. It is adjusted based on the plot's `x` values. The intercept in this case is the adjusted mean value of `y` or the hold-out category.

You could leave out the intercept and get the adjusted mean for each group directly by running the `lm` model as follows:

```
m.lm2 <- lm(y ~ x + type + 0, data=dat.A) // +0 removes the intercept
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you recommendation (to use `lmer` as in the 1st code section) remain the same, assuming there are more observations? This is a subset of the data just for illustration, the real data has ~3 times more observations.

Comment: If you only have 3 soil samples, then it would be a bit of a stretch. There's no right number for how many groups you need, but 5 is better than 3 and 10 is better than 5. If I were in your boat, assuming only 3 soil samples, I'd probably use `lm`.